# new referencing outlet, view to UIviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

So, I'm following this tutorial on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8hCmTA_7cE). I want to add a pie chart to my app. However, when I try adding a new referencing outlet from my `PieChart view` to `my view controller`(done at 5:01), Xcode doesn't let me do that. Any way to fix this?

Here's my view controller.m

```
//
//  checkAttendanceViewController.m
//  timetable app
//
//  Created by Robin Malhotra on 29/12/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Robin's code kitchen. All rights reserved.
//

#import "checkAttendanceViewController.h"

@interface checkAttendanceViewController ()

@end

@implementation checkAttendanceViewController

@synthesize pieChartView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        NSNumber *number=[NSNumber numberWithInt:rand()%60+20];
        [array addObject:number];

    }

    [self.pieChartView renderInLayer:self.pieChartView dataArray:array];

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

and my viewcontroller.h

```
//
//  checkAttendanceViewController.h
//  timetable app
//
//  Created by Robin Malhotra on 29/12/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Robin's code kitchen. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DLPieChart.h"


@interface checkAttendanceViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet DLPieChart *pieChartView;
@end
```

Here's a [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ivl6nw6nw8p9j1y/MDwYDaHVH_) link if anyone wants to try it out themselves(I know I'm not supposed to share external links, but I've pasted appropriate code and I'm not sure how you paste a storyboard in stackoverflow

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z5uwu0wksa1e9ya/uXAQm6ACq- here's teh dropbox DL link

Comment: I just checked your iPhone storyboard. I do not see any view controller containing a DLPiechart type of UIView in it. Neither you have added this framework in your project.

Comment: I forgot to mention, it's in the "Final" Folder. Open the S\Xcode project in that and you'll find the view(it's right below my nav controller

Answer (score 1):

When this happens to me it is usually because the view's class type in the xib does not match the outlet class type in the source file.

- Select the view in your storyboard or xib
- Choose View->Utilities->Show Identity Inspector (visible on the right side of Xcode)
- Ensure the "Custom Class" textfield is set to "DLPieChart" (the type defined in your outlet)

Comment: Done and Done. No Dice. Any other way to fix?

Comment: Similarly, make sure the ViewController in the storyboard has the correct class name. - Select the View Controller in the storyboard, view the Identity Inspector, and make sure the Custom Class is set to the correct value. Based on your code above it should be "checkAttendanceViewController"

Comment: Okay, it suddenly started working. I quitted and restarted Xcode, cleaned the project, and voila, it  works now. Should I remove this question now?

Comment: Better to just answer your own question (restarting Xcode fixed it). That way you might help someone else who runs into that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I see the issue. You have wrongly set the name of the viewController class as "checkAttendanceViewContriller" instead of "checkAttendanceViewController" in your story board view controller. Change the name and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it suddenly started working. I quitted and restarted Xcode, cleaned the project, and voila, it  works now. Should I remove this question now?.